# JavaScript Допишите код который возводит число 2 в степень 10. Использовать цикл for.

Tags: javascript

Только учусь, вот мой набросок. Чего не хватает?

```
var num=2;
var exp=10;
var count=2;    
var result=num;

for(var count=2; count<=exp; count++){  
    console.log(count);
}
```

Должно в консоли выводится число 1024.

Comment: эмм..если вы хотите возвести число в n-ую степень, то, как подсказывает элементарная математика, это самое число нужно умножить само на себя n раз. Однако же вы этого не делаете, вместо этого зачем-то выводя на консоль значение счетчика

Comment: помогите разобраться, что нужно исправить? console.log убрал.

Comment: для Вас это детская задача, самому не получается разобраться, просто прошу помочь.

Comment: мой комментарий выше предназначен как раз для того, чтобы вам помочь. Если вы знаете, что такое возведение в степень и умеете умножать числа, то, думаю, проблем тут быть не должно

Comment: я знаю что такое возведение в степень, но как в как это изобразить в коде я не знаю. Если я правильно понимаю счетчик count считает до exp равной 10, тогда как num перемножить на себя 10 раз и вывести в консоль?

Comment: @Kimosabe, result = result*num. Дальше сами.

Comment: @Kimosabe прежде чем что-либо делать (в том числе и писать код), имеет смысл ознакомиться с тем, как же все-таки это делается. Если хотите написать возведение в степень, то почитайте про [арифметические операторы][1]


  [1]: http://javascript.ru/arithmetic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Давайте сначала алгоритм опишем. «2 в степени 10» значит, нужно 10 двоек перемножить. `2 * 2 * 2 ... * 2` — двойка десять раз, умножение 9 раз.

Чтобы не писать длинную колбасу умножений, сделаем в цикле, как просят.

Пусть будет переменная `result`, где хранится текущее значение умножения. И внутри цикла, который прокрутим 9 раз (сколько раз «умножение»), будем домножать на 2:

```
for( блаблабла) {
    result = result * 2;
}
```

Этот `result` после девяти раз будет содержать требуемый результат.

Осталось оформить цикл. Внутри идёт три выражения:

1. Начальные значения.
2. Условия, которые должны выполняться. Как только нарушатся — выйдем из цикла.
3. Действия на каждом повторе.

Сделаем с переменной счётчиком `i`. Повторим 9 раз, каждый раз уменьшаем на 1. Крутим, пока не дойдём до нуля:

```
for( i=9; i>0; i=i-1)
```

И, наконец, в самом начале надо объявить/дать начальные значения всем переменным:

```
var i, result, exp=10, num=2;
```

Дальше соберите, пожалуйста, самостоятельно. Здесь почти всё. В цикле стоит вместо фиксированного значения использовать переменную `exp`.

Answer (score 4):

```
function power(base, exp){
    var result = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i <exp; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return(result);
}
console.log(power(2,10));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var num = 2;
var exp = 10;
var result = 1;
var cnt = 1;
while (cnt <= exp){
  result = result * num;
  console.log(result)
  cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: A что вам не было понятно

Comment: Ну, например мне не понятно, зачем давать в качестве ответа код, очень близкий к вопросу, но явно и, вероятно, намеренно нарущающий одно из требований вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

```
function power (base, exponent) {
if (exponent == 0) {
return 1; 
} else {
return base * power(base, exponent - 1)
}
}
console.log(power(2,10);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]